# Draw a perfect circle on texture

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I want to draw two perfect circles on a sphere that would function as the sphere's eyes.

When I go to to the Texture Paint and try to draw two circles they are hardly perfect:
[image]

How can I draw two perfect circles in Texture Paint?

Is there an option to choose a geometrical shape and just adjust its size instead of drawing it from scratch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem that there is any inner tool to easily draw a circle or a square in *Texture Paint* mode, that said you can use the trick explained [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/doesnt-texture-paint-need-a-little-bit-more-tools-like-drawing-a-shape/1276857/2) by Nwytg:

- Choose *Stroke Method > Anchored*:

[image]

- Create this kind of *Falloff* that will make the circle empty:

[image]

Left click at the center of the circle and drag:

[image]

Or keep the same *Falloff* but choose *Stroke Method > Dots*, press <kbd>F</kbd> to set the circle radius, and left click to create the circle:

[image]

Comment: Interesting use of the custom brush falloff. Smart !

Answer (score 0):

You could make the brush very large and sharp to match the outer diameter of the eye and then erase or paint with base color the inner diameter of the eye.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iPhone or iPad you can stroke the circles in Tintaur app with two linked arcs and then export ready-to-use spherical textures. Here's [a short video](https://youtu.be/r3lNxbeD7u0) explaining the process.

Comment: This looks like a smartphone app ad.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: you're wrong then.